# How to use JavaSound Midi on Linux using FireWire AudioInterface?

Tags: audio, alsa, javasound, jack, soundcard

I'm using QJackCtl and FireWire Audio Interface(Edirol FireWire AudioCapture FA-101).

I made program which connect JavaSound Synthesizer Gervill and External USB Midi Keyboard, it triggers Gervill synthesizer.

I can use this without QJackCtl(jack with ffado firewire backend), so default native midi system, but with jack, I can't use this because JavaSound doesn't support jack. Program not respond to USB-Keyboard while launching Jack(QJackCtl).

I'm wondering I can use this audio interface setting jack(qjackctl) correctly.

FireWire audio interface is not supported by pulseaudio and ALSA, it should use ffado. So can't use ALSA. If edit midi routing, a2j should be used.

Can I use j2amidi_bridge to use bridge port in Java Sound application and trigger Java Sound synthesizer by USB-Keyboard?

```
public void printMidiDeviceInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<midiDeviceInfo.length;i++)
                {
                    MidiDevice midiDevice=MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(midiDeviceInfo[i]);
                    print(
                    "Midi機器情報配列["+i+"] 説明:"+this.midiDeviceInfo[i].getDescription()+
                    "\n     ベンダー情報:"+this.midiDeviceInfo[i].getVendor()+
                    "\n     バージョン:"+this.midiDeviceInfo[i].getVersion()+
                    "\n     toString(): "+this.midiDeviceInfo[i].toString()+
                    "\n     シンセサイザー:"+(midiDevice instanceof Synthesizer)+
                    "\n     シーケンサー:"+(midiDevice instanceof Sequencer)+"\n\n"
                    );
                } 
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
        } 
    }
```

I tried to use j2amidi_bridge "bridge_name" device on my application,
and I searched the bridge device by code above. But I couldn't find the j2amidi_bridge device.

And j2amidi_bridge -e &; made connection between my Java Sound application and jack(qjackctl) but synthesizer latency got worse than default device on my iMac 2011.

Comment: I could use JavaSound on Jack(include QJackCtl) environment using j2amidi_bridge.
j2amidi_bridge "bridge name" connected midi while using Audio Interface on Jack.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code? And what have you tried?